# 'NgIf' is neither 'ComponentType' or 'DirectiveType'

Tags: angular, angular-directive

When using *ngIf in a very simple component, I get the error in the title. For example, below code and app.module cause this:

app.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="true">
  <div>True</div>
</ng-container>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am very confused as to what could be causing this. *ngFor directive has the same problem.
The rest of the project comes directly from `ng new` generated files.

`"@angular/core": "~11.2.8"`

Comment: BrowserModule also re-exports CommonModule from @angular/common, which means that components in the AppModule module also have access to the Angular directives every app needs, such as NgIf and NgFor.

@IngoBürk

Comment: In addition, I get another error for which I find little to no resource online when adding CommonModule to app.module: `Type CommonModule does not have 'ɵmod' property.`.

Comment: You're right, apologies. Any chance you can upload the repository to GitHub or something? Sounds like it's basically empty anyway, right? A standard thing to try would be deleting node_modules and reinstalling.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try doing that. :-) If not, I'll upload to Github. @IngoBürk

Comment: *sighs* That did it. Thanks for your help, I'll answer this question to avoid headaches to future people! @IngoBürk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A corrupted or otherwise weird `node_modules` is most likely the source of the problem.

Running `npm ci` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is because NgIf is declared in common module

Add & import the module in your app module or any other module that wants to utilize common directives.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
```

This is very common mistake when people forget to import the things they require in angular runtime, since each module imports and exports their own set of object, you need to specify what needs to be done and at the end compiler will shake tree to import necessary modules and class code with chunks.

[NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) Directive Documentation states that to use the modifier you need commons module

so your code should look like :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: To quote the docs:
> BrowserModule also re-exports CommonModule from @angular/common, which means that components in the AppModule module also have access to the Angular directives every app needs, such as NgIf and NgFor.

BrowserModule re-exports CommonModule, making the double import useless. There are some cases where importing CommonModule is useful, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue. It was an organisation's internal library which was causing this problem. I reinstalled the package which was causing the issue. That fixed it for me. Also, try removing and reinstalling node_modules and package-lock.json as well.